# Entity Framework, Oracle, DevArt, Context#ExecuteStoreQuery: System.Int32 constructed as System.Double?

Tags: entity-framework-4, devart

I have an Entity-class having a Property of type Int32: on generating DDL using DevArt for ORACLE a NUMBER(10) column is generated. Reading and writing instances works flawlessly.

However, on fetching instances of this Entity-class sending a custom query to ExecuteStoreQuery on the ObjectContext this Property seems to be returned as System.Double, as such constructing the instances fails.

Can I hint DevArt to construct System.Int32?

Thank you.
Bart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is the fact that OracleDataReader, which is used in the ExecuteStoreQuery method, has type mapping different from the one used in the Entity Framework provider.
I recommend you to use [NumberMappings](http://www.devart.com/blogs/dotconnect/index.php/new-features-of-entity-framework-support-in-dotconnect-providers.html#NumberMappings), I suppose you will need to map Number(10) to Int32: `Number Mappings=((NUMBER,10,10,System.Int32)`. These changes should be persisted to the model connection string (they are duplicating the default EF mapping rules, it is necessary for the OracleDataReader from ExecuteStoreQuery).
Please let us know if the problem persists.